# SQL Triggers lists Oracle

Tags: oracle, list, triggers

I have a table Giving(donor, receiver, giftname) that lists who gave gifts to whom.  I am trying to write a trigger that will fire off if it's the first gift given by the donor, the first gift received by the receiver, or if it's the first gift for both donor and receiver.  Essentially what I need to do is compare the new donor's name against the list of all donors and make sure it's not there yet.  Then do the same for receivers.  This is my attempt, but I'm sure it's not right because my variables existingreceivers and existingdonors aren't going to do what I want them to do.  Will these variables existingreceivers and existingdonors store multiple values?  If not, how do I accomplish what I need to do?

```
create or replace TRIGGER FirstGift
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF donor,receiver ON GIVING
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
ExistingReceivers varchar(255);
ExistingDonors varchar(255);

BEGIN
select donor into existingdonors
from giving;

select receiver into existingreceivers
from giving;

--first gift for donor, first gift for receiver
if(:new.donor not in existingdonors and :new.receiver not in existingreceivers)then
dbms_output.put_line('This is the first gift received by ', :new.receiver, 'and the first given by ', :new.donor);
insert into messages (intid, donor, receiver, giftname, msg) values (test_seq.nextval, :new.donor, :new.receiver, :new.giftname, 'First Gift Given and First Received!');


--first gift for donor, not first gift for receiver
elsif(:new.donor not in existingdonors)then
dbms_output.put_line('This is the first gift given by ', :new.donor);
insert into messages (intid, donor, receiver, giftname, msg) values (test_seq.nextval, :new.donor, :new.receiver, :new.giftname, 'First Gift Given!');

--first gift for receiver, not first gift for donor
elsif(:new.receiver not in existingreceivers)then
dbms_output.put_line('This is the first gift received by ', :new.receiver);
insert into messages (intid, donor, receiver, giftname, msg) values (test_seq.nextval, :new.donor, :new.receiver, :new.giftname, 'First Gift Received!');

end if;

end;
```

Comment: What's incorrect about the existingdonors and existingreceivers variables? Just trying to understand what might need to be changed to do what you want.

Comment: As I understand you try to query a table which is mutating, that is, a trigger is fired upon a DML operation on a table and you try to query/update the very same table by the very same fired trigger. This could lead to ORA-04091 error. You may want to use an "Instead of" trigger or making your trigger as "Autonomous Transaction".

Comment: Error(18,22): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXISTINGDONORS" when expecting one of the following:     ( The symbol "(" was substituted for "EXISTINGDONORS" to continue.

Error(18,62): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXISTINGRECEIVERS" when expecting one of the following:     (

Comment: I guess I'm thinking this won't work, because I don't believe the variables existingdonors and existingreceivers each store multiple values?  Am I correct in thinking this?

Answer (score 2):

We better help you to get this working before Tuesday, don't we. (Is it you, Santa???)

Your approach should work fine, just change the detail from a list of all gift to the number of gifts, which is easier to query and store. You could query the number of gifts given by donor, received by receiver and exchanged by the pair using three queries in the trigger like thus (I left out the INSERT INTO MESSAGES bit):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FirstGift
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF donor, receiver ON GIVING FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  num_donor     NUMBER;
  num_receiver  NUMBER;
  num_both      NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO num_both
    FROM giving
   WHERE donor = :new.donor AND receiver = :new.receiver;

  SELECT count(*) INTO num_donor
    FROM giving
   WHERE donor = :new.donor;       

  SELECT count(*) INTO num_receiver
    FROM giving
   WHERE donor = :new.donor;  

  IF num_both = 0 THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line(:new.donor||' and '||:new.receiver);
  ELSE 
    IF num_donor = 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(:new.donor);
    END IF;

    IF num_receiver = 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(:new.receiver);
    END IF;
END;
/
```

If the table gets huge, you could solve it with a single query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FastFirstGift
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF donor, receiver ON GIVING FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  num_donor     NUMBER;
  num_receiver  NUMBER;
  num_both      NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN donor    = :new.donor    THEN 1 END),
         SUM(CASE WHEN receiver = :new.receiver THEN 1 END),
         SUM(CASE WHEN donor    = :new.donor
                   AND receiver = :new.receiver THEN 1 END)
    INTO num_donor, num_receiver, num_both
  FROM giving;

  IF num_both = 0 THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line(:new.donor||' and '||:new.receiver);
  ELSE 
    IF num_donor = 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(:new.donor);
    END IF;

    IF num_receiver = 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(:new.receiver);
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Hope that answers your question...